# I'm in construction

Tags: sentence-meaning

I read from a book:

What do you do?/ What is your job?
I'm in construction.
I'm in retail.

Do the answers "I'm in construction." & "I'm in retail." mean "I work in the construction industry" & "I work in the retail industry" respectively? Can someone explain a little more about them?

Comment: Yes they do. It is a shortcut, but nowadays you wouldn't use the long form unless you were being formal.

Comment: They mean more like: *I'm in the construction business* and *I'm in the retail business*.

Comment: Also, “in construction” and the like can mean anything from owning a business to casual labor.

Comment: Sorry, I don't pretty understand this point. What do you mean by 'owning a business to casual labor'?

Comment: It's ungrammatical to say: *I don't "pretty" understand*. The adverb "pretty" is used with adjectives e.g It's pretty difficult, they're pretty good, pretty fantastic,  etc. You need **quite** in "I don't quite understand"

Comment: A person can say they are "in construction" if they own a construction company or even if they are only a hired laborer/worker/ builder etc.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

When a person says that they are *in construction* then they are saying that they work in the construction industry. It doesn’t convey any further information as to at what level in the industry, i.e. whether they own a construction business or mix muck for the bricklayer.

It is often used in social events such as parties, as a quick response to a general question, e.g. *what’s your line? I’m in ......*.

It is also used in comedy, such as a man who works in a department store might say *I’m in women’s underwear*.